# How to pass the request parameter in Restful webservice's header?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restful-url

The webservice i am using will receive two parameter such as "username" and "password".

When i send a request to service, i'm passing the parameter in the url itself

```
$scope.testService=function() {
 alert("TestService"); 
  $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'testurl/authenticate?username=suren&password=raja' , headers:{'Authorization':'sdgfdgdsg','Content-Type':'application/json'}}).
  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  alert(data);
});
```

};

It is returning the response i need. But i need the parameter to be passed in header instead of URL.

Can anyone tell me the syntax for it.

Thanks,
Surendher

Comment: try using `data` attribute of $http

Comment: Use the headers object, which you're already using in that call.

Comment: @MarcKline Can you share me the sample code